# Backup remote server over ssh without using root

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, remote-access, rsync

I want to backup a folder in a remote server. The files in the folder are owned by different users. The remote server cannot be connected by root using ssh. How can I do the backup?

I was trying with rsync:

```
rsync -e ssh -vauzP --delete remote_user@{REMOTE_IP}:/home/remote_user/folder/ /home/local_user/backup/
```

But I get 'permission denied' messages for the files that remote_user doesn't own.

Answer (score 3):

You could `ssh` to the remote machine as some user who has `sudo` rights, and have that user give the `rsync` command from the other end. Something like this (untested):

```
ssh remote_user@{REMOTE_IP} 'rsync -e ssh -vauzP --delete /home/remote_user/folder/ local_user@{LOCAL_IP}:/home/local_user/backup/'
```

Where `local_user` and `LOCAL_IP` are the user and machine where you are currently logged in.

Comment: But I'm behind a router with closed remote access. With your solution I should allow it, right? Is there any other option?